# How do I access the home directory in a different OS

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I figure this is a basic question already answered, but I can't seem to word it quite right to find anything in search.  Basically, I was wondering how to read a file in a home partition assigned to a different OS on my computer.

My set up: I have Windows 10, Mint cinnamon, Ubuntu studio, and Ubuntu MATE installed on a DIY desktop with three different hard drives.  Drive 1 is Windows, drive 2 is split between Windows and the home partition for Ubuntu studio, and drive 3 is split between the roots of Mint, Ubuntu studio, and Ubuntu MATE.  Drive 3 also contains home partitions for mint and MATE as well as a swap partition for all three Linux OS.

Basically I want to read a iso file in the mint home directory from the MATE OS.

Answer (score 1):

Umm, basically between the Linuxes there should be no problem, you can just use the file manager and those partitions should show up. To mount the Windows partitions you might need root.

To make it easier, you could automatically mount them or even use the same home directory for multiple Linuxes (can lead to problems), for this you would need to learn about the /etc/fstab configuration file.

To access the Linux partitions (which I hope are ext?-file systems) you need a special driver on Windows, there are like two or three to choose from, a quick search for "ext file system windows" should find them.

Comment: Quote: "To access the Linux partitions (which I hope are ext?-file systems) you need a special driver on Windows". Thanks! That's something whole new to me! Until now, I knew that Windows just can't "see" Linux partitions, much less access the data on them!

Comment: It  is not a good idea to use the same home-directory for different Linux-distributions. You would mess up with configuration-files stored in /home unless you use different user-names in each distribution.

Comment: @mook765 I think it's more of a risk than certainty that something will break? But I guess I should add a warning.

Comment: Hello, I wasn't trying to share a home directory, i have a separate home directory for each os.  I wanted to read the home director from a different OS.  I was able to figure this out using "disks".

Comment: "Disks" is a partitioning utility in Gnome, isn't it? You don't need it. Just use "Files".

Answer (score 0):

You can manually mount the other partitions using `Terminal` but being somewhat "terminally challenged" I prefer to use Nautilus to mount the partitions for me:

[image]

On the left pane are all the drives and partitions. They default as unmounted but when you click on them they mount and the eject icon appears after them.

After mounting you can click on the drive / partition and navigate to your ISO.

If you prefer to use `Terminal` to access your files (after partition is mounted) you can see the drives and partitions with the `lsblk` command:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part 
└─sda2   8:2    0   118G  0 part /media/rick/KSX_Win7
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   100M  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0 257.4G  0 part /media/rick/ST9_Win7
├─sdb3   8:19   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdb5   8:21   0 200.5G  0 part /media/rick/ST9_Linux
└─sdb6   8:22   0   7.9G  0 part 
sdc      8:32   0 119.2G  0 disk 
├─sdc2   8:34   0  78.1G  0 part /media/rick/F9m_Win7
├─sdc3   8:35   0  29.3G  0 part /
└─sdc4   8:36   0   7.8G  0 part [SWAP]
sdd      8:48   0 186.3G  0 disk 
├─sdd1   8:49   0   1.5G  0 part 
├─sdd2   8:50   0 178.9G  0 part /media/rick/S3A6550D005
└─sdd3   8:51   0     6G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Seeing the format in `lsblk` you can use that to `cd` to any drive and partition to navigate to your .iso file. ie `cd /media/rick/S3A6550D005`

Although Nautilus is used for Ubuntu 16.04 similar file managers exist in other OSes and the Terminal is likely the same.

HTH.

Comment: @ThomasYun why? you can do this with -any- file browser and also always on command line too